# Button on my jsp page not linking to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi ive been trying to get my 'Start Auction' button to link to a controller class with no luck.

This is the button within the jsp page-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><a href="../aucConfirm/${newAuction.idauction}/start" >Start Auction</a></button>
```

These are the two controller methods that, confirmAuction has a model.AddAttribute line-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aucConfirm/{idauction}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confirmAuction(@PathVariable(value = "idauction") int idauction, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        AuctionItem addAuction = (AuctionItem) aucRepository.findOne(idauction);
        model.addAttribute("newAuction", addAuction);
        model.addAttribute("startAction", addAuction.getIdauction() + "/start");
        return "aucConfirm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/aucConfirm/{idauction}/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String startAuction(@PathVariable(value = "idauction") int idauction, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        AuctionItem addAuction = (AuctionItem) aucRepository.findOne(idauction);

        List<Image> imageList = (List<Image>) imageRepository.findByidauction(idauction);
        addAuction.setMainImage(imageList.get(0).getImagepath());
        addAuction.setActive(true);
        aucRepository.save(addAuction);
        return "redirect:/listing/" + idauction;

    }
```

Anyone know why this button isnt working? It doesnt do anything at all, not even an error message.

Comment: remove 2 dots in your href

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy thanks for the help, but still nothing happening

Comment: Change your button type to <button type="submit" > (if you're submitting form data)

Comment: @dsp_user im not submitting form data unfortunately

Comment: Post your web.xml

Comment: You wrote that after clicking nothing happens, so try to remove tag button, its not necessary to have anchor in button, maybe button blocks click event on this anchor.

Comment: @glw removed  type="button" still no response

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy i dont have a web.xml, dont think i need one

Comment: Remove whole tag, not type, so you have only: `<a href="../aucConfirm/${newAuction.idauction}/start" >Start Auction</a>`

Comment: @glw Thank you, the button now directs to the url however i get a 404 error, any ideas?

Comment: Probably wrong path in href. Maybe you're missing context or controller path. Or maybe you don't need `..`

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><a class="pull-right" role="button" href="<c:url value="/aucConfirm/${newAuction.idauction}/start" />">Start Auction</a></button>